# Подключение библиотеки jQuery UI Select2 в проекте C# asp net core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

Проект C# asp net core. Использую jQuery v3.5.1 и BootStrap 4.

Есть Select:

```
<div id="divHouse" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select class="selectСhoice" id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses"></select>
        </div>
```

Делаю поиск для данного Select, чтобы при его активации можно было не крутить, а начать вводить и отображались подходящие варианты. Реализовываю на фронте.

Для реализации выбрал библиотеку jQuery UI Select2 (https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)

Согласно оф докам добавил ссылки на зависимости для select2:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

прописал функцию:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selectСhoice').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
                placeholder: "Выберите дом",
                minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
                maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
                language: "ru"
            });
        });
```

При срабатывании обработчика выдает ошибку, что нет такой функции:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function TypeError:
> $(...).select2 is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:362:27)
> at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307)
> undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (Create:362)
> at e (VM18 jquery.min.js:2)
> at t (VM18 jquery.min.js:2)

Пробовал устанавливать через npm:

```
npm install select2
```

А потом прописывать ссылки как описано в доках:

```
<link href="vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Ошибка:

> GET
> http://localhost:18246/Friends/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Create:201 GET
> http://localhost:18246/Friends/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Create:200 GET
> http://localhost:18246/Friends/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Create:201 GET
> http://localhost:18246/Friends/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Папка, которая указывается в ссылках в проекте не создается.

Как правильно подключить данную библиотеку в проект C# asp net core?

Скопировал папку dist c папками css и js в папку проекта "wwwroot/lib", прописал пути:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/lib/dist_select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/dist_select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Ошибка:

> jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a
> function TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:363:32)
> at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307)
> undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (Create:363)
> at e (VM11 jquery.min.js:2)
> at t (VM11 jquery.min.js:2)

Исходники html страниц:

```
    @model voteCollector.Models.Friend

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions {
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Friend</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken"
           name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FamilyName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FamilyName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FamilyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PatronymicName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PatronymicName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PatronymicName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateBirth" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="CityId" asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CityId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DistrictId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DistrictId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DistrictId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="StreetId" asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
            </div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MicroDistrictId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="MicroDistrictId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MicroDistrictId"></select>
            </div>*@
            <div id="divHouse" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="selectСhoice" id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses"></select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GroupUId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="GroupUId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GroupUId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/lib/dist_select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/dist_select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</environment>

@section Scripts {

    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selectСhoice').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
                placeholder: "Выберите дом",
                minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
                maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
                language: "ru"
            });
        });

    </script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    @{
        if (TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            <script>
            alert('@TempData["msg"]')
            </script>
        }
    }
```

Из браузера:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Create - voterCollector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />

    


    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогичная ситуация возникает при попытке подключения других JS-библиотек. Н-р:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function
> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:18246/Friends:470:31)
> at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307)
> undefined
>
> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (Friends:470)
> at e (VM319 jquery.min.js:2)
> at t (VM319 jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: руками скопировать файл в указанную папку например, либо настроить NPM так, чтобы он положил файл туда, куда вам надо при установке, сейчас он явно кладет не туда.

Comment: @aepot, как настроить npm? Не хотелось бы руками, потому что бы при переносе или запуске проекта на др ПК не было проблем

Comment: в любом случае, css и js файлы - это статика, просто положите внутрь web root. При копировании вы в любом случае этот каталог потащите с собой, так что не должно ничего потеряться. Для начала заставьте это всё работать, а уже потом разбирайтесь с тем, как заставить это работат красиво.

Comment: @aepot, скопировал папку dist c папками css и js в папку проекта "wwwroot/lib", прописал пути - ошибка. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: А исходнике HTML страницы, которая подгружена в браузер, эти ссылки есть?

Comment: @aepot, да. Дополнил вопрос исходником

Comment: Вы не Blazor страницу смотрите, а браузере через инспектор

Comment: @aepot, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Кажется то, чо у вас в браузере, отличается от того что в странице. Но не суть, ссылки вроде рабочие.

Comment: @aepot, да, но судя по содержанию ошибок он все равно пытается все тянуть из локального реестра jquery, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Поробуйте для начала получить хоть так ваш select

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectСhoice').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
        placeholder: "Выберите дом",
        minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
        maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
        language: "ru"
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="divHouse" class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select class="selectСhoice form-control" id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses" style="width:100%"></select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Та же самая ошибка : 'jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:18246/Friends/Create:363:32)
    at e (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (http://localhost:18246/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined'

Comment: Почему локалхост. Поставьте как есть

Comment: Вы меняете оригинал потом говорите ошибка. Оставьте как есть

Comment: у себя на странице я прописал как у вас - просто скопировал, но где-то ведать идет подмена

Comment: В jdom видать есть ещё подгрузка. jQuery самого. И он обнуляет ваши изменения

Comment: Это где? Как это исправить?

Comment: Смотрите в инструментах разработчика. Когда и кто подгружает jQuery. В очередной раз

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы внешние библиотеки проекта asp net core подтянулись в проект нужно прописать ссылки на них на странице проекта Layuot.chtml  в блоке:

```
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
 
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
```